# Save data from json in internal device

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this code in my apps:

```
struct ServerConnect {
    enum Result<T> {
        case succes(T)
        case error(String)
    }

    typealias completionHandler = (Result<Data >) -> ()

    func getJsonFromServer(parameters: String, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        let fullUrlString = ApiConstans.fullPath + parameters
        guard let url = URL(string: fullUrlString) else {
            debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect01)")
            return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect01)"))
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect02)")
                return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect02)"))
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                debugPrint("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect03)")
                return completion(.error("\(ErrorsLabels.ServerConnect03)"))
            }

            debugPrint("R> \(fullUrlString)")
            return completion(.succes(data))
            }.resume()
    }


    func getJsonProducts(lang: String?, region: Int?, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
        self.getJsonFromServer(parameters: "?action=GET_PRODUCTS&lang=\(lang!)&region=\(region!)", completion: completion)
    }

}
```

I want save data to my device with this code:

```
let cms = ServerConnect()
cms.getJsonProducts(lang: selectedLanguage, region: selectedRegion , completion: { (data) in
    switch data {
    case .succes(let data):
        self.saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: selectedLanguage + "/json/temp.json",  downloadData: data)
    case .error(let error):
        self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "\(ErrorsLabels.MainViewControler01). \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
        break
    }
})


func saveJsonFileToTheDisk(path: String, downloadData: Data){
    do {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        try downloadData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch { self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "\(ErrorsLabels.MainViewControler02). \(error)", title: "Blad".localized()) }
}
```

Unfortunately, the application does not save the file to disk (it does not even create it). I have error:

> "The folder temp.json doesn't exist.
>   UserInfo=PNSFilePath=Users/mymac/Library/Developer........./json/temp.json.
>   .... No such file or directory             ";

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually create the folder and the file and then write to it.

The code below checks that the folder exists and if it not, it creates it.

then it does the same with the file.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let demoJson = """
    { "name": "John Smith" }
    """
    let folderName = "json"
    let fileName = "demo.json"
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        createFolderIfNotExists(name: folderName)
        saveJson(json: demoJson, toFile: "/\(folderName)/\(fileName)")

        let filePath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("/\(folderName)/\(fileName)")
        fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path)

        print("[DEBUG] - File exits value: \(fileExists)")
        print(try? String(contentsOf: filePath))
    }

    func createFolderIfNotExists(name: String) {
        let path = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent(name)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
            return
        } else {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func saveJson(json: String, toFile: String) {
        let path = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent(toFile)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path) {
            return
        }

        if let data = json.data(using: .utf8), FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path.path, contents: data, attributes: nil) {
            try? data.write(to: path)
        }
    }
}
```